# Is this a misuse of the word "evaluate"?

Tags: terminology, continued-fractions

I have found the following use of the word "evaluate" in several math books:

"To evaluate the continued fraction, start at the bottom and work your way up:"

$\huge \underbrace{2 + \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3}}}=2 + \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}}=2+\frac{3}{4}= \underbrace{\frac{11}{4}}$  Why is this called an "evaluation" and not a simplification?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory#Normalization) may be of interest.

Comment: Because clearly fractions and decimals are the right way of representing numbers, not continued fractions. This is entirely a product of how we've been trained to think about numbers.

Comment: That doesn't contradict the use of the word "evaluate"; it simply means that "evaluate" and "simplify" are equally good words to use to describe this particular procedure.

Comment: Where are you getting your definitions from? Evaluating is just determining the numerical value of an expression; the exact meaning of "numerical value" is cultural.

Comment: I just checked the index of my Algebra textbook (Dummit & Foote) for the word "evaluate", and found the evaluation homomorphism from a polynomial ring. Indeed, you are right; I'm pretty sure that is not what we are discussing in this context. (NOTE: this is a joke.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because people commonly use the word *evaluate* in that context; this is simply a fact of usage. You can see other examples [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/3.10#iii) on the website of the National Institute of Standards and Technology, in the title of [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2027965?uid=3739840&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21103012160577) in *SIAM Review*, and [here](http://nrich.maths.org/1352), to pick three of the first few examples that turned up on a search. In this context *evaluate* simply isn’t the technical term whose definition you give in the comments; it’s another sense of the same word.

Comment: @badass: No: this is a normal usage of the word *evaluate*, so by definition it makes sense. *Simplify* also makes sense; which one uses here is largely a matter of taste and context. If I were talking to a bunch of fifth-graders and dealing with relatively ‘short’ continued fractions, I might well use *simplify*; in most contexts, however, I’d probably use *evaluate*.

Comment: @badass: I agree with Peterson that $\frac{m}n$ is proper if $|m|<|n|$. It’s also true that use of the term *proper fraction* is largely limited to the early grades, before the question of negative fractions arises, and there’s no telling how any given fourth grade teacher, say, would answer the question ‘Is $-2/3$ a proper fraction?’